# Rails Bootstrap menu works in production but dont works in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

My bootstrap dropdown menu works in production mode in my computer when i use:

```
$ rails s -e production
```

But when i push my app in Heroku, dont works dropdown menu

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .


  config.assets.compile = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: Do you have added css file names in /environments/productions.rb file:
config.assets.precompile += []

Comment: Did you add the 12factor gem to your gemfile for production?

Comment: yes hi have the gem in gemfile

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
 gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'
end

Comment: i have 
 # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

how can i use?